# No Visual property of RowDetalsTemplate in the data grid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to add row details to each row, however I don't find RowDetailsTemplate property in the datagrid to add row details through UI. Do I need to manually change xaml?

I am using recent version of WPF Toolkit which requires 3.5 Sp1. Also using Visual Studio 2008 Sp1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property grid of the XAML Designer in VS 2008 generally doesn't show any properties of type FrameworkTemplate (and derived types, like DataTemplate). Only the VS2010 designer added these properties, and lets you select an existing template resource.

So, short reply: Yes, in VS2008, you have to manually edit the XAML in order to define a RowDetailsTemplate.